# Problem in adding geoJSON "info"

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I have problem with display geojson "info".When I "click" on geojson layer I see also previous "info". In result I see multiple information.
I would like to see only one info .[image] (3 times i cicked in one place)Below is my script:

```
      map.on('click', function(e) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature) {
    return feature;
  });


  var infoElement = document.getElementById('info');
 // infoElement.innerHTML = feature ? feature.get('gml_id') : '';
   $(info).append('<b>Title</b> : '+feature.get('gml_id')+'<br/> <b>Title</b> : '+feature.get('gml_id'))
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more information on your issue, for example what software are you using (is it OpenLayers?)

Comment: Yes it openlayer3. Below my script:                                          https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5em3mVKE2w . Everything works but I see multiple "info"text

Comment: You should add your comment information to the question (using the edit function); also you shouldn't expect people answering the question to have to go off site, so perhaps you could post a screen shot of the problem too.

Comment: Sorry, I add image with problem. In console I dont see a error